# weblogic stop writing logs and shutdown

Tags: weblogic, shutdown, freeze

Maybe someone had the same problem.
I use Weblogic at work. So, we have two small  applications on it. And today it stopped writing logs(all logs stopped writing at the same time). Then, after three hours it writes in log “JVM called WLS shutdown hook. The server will force shutdown now”  and shutdown. After start everything works fine.
But I want to understand, why this situation happened

Thanks

Comment: Its in your own machine,  and  are you  the administrator of the weblogic?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when System.exit(int) is called. Check if some of the deployed components call System.exit instead of throwing an Exception. This also can be due to the JVM taking up the OS signals.Set the -Xrs option in the startup scripts in JAVA_OPTIONS if you are using Sun JDK.It reduces use of operating-system signals by the JVM.